# My PC restart when playing games, not sure what happen

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer, gaming, temperature

I have a problem with my PC and I can't figure out what can be wrong. If I am playing games, the PC will restart after 30-40 minutes of gaming.

Here's a picture of the temperatures and the voltages after 20 minutes of gaming, bc I think it's a power supply problem.

[image: Temperatures]

[image: Voltages]

Main componentes are:

1. MSI B350 Tomahawk
2. GTX 1060 6GB MSI
3. Ryzen 1600X
4. An old Nox PSU of 650W

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: Problem is that the PC restart suddenly after a 20-30 minutes of playing any game that demand a little more of my PC. Just playing and whops, black screen and PC is restarting itself.

In case you want to know some componentes: MSI B350 Tomahawk, GTX 1060 6GB MSI and Ryzen 1600X

Comment: Your PSU is more then adequate for a 3 generation old GPU.  Why do you suspect the PSU is the problem?

Comment: If you suspect the PSU why don't you try changing PSU?  Changing suspect parts is the way to troubleshoot!

Comment: @Ramhound I suspect because the voltage go down and down when playing, the +12V can go down even to 10.8, and maybe it's causing instability.

Comment: @barlop I don't have money neither other PSU, I should wait until next month :(